# Extracting items of different layouts from lists

Tags: python, list, extract, items

I have a strangely behaving file from a Linux program; example firt etn lines are:

```
 1 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0           191340          ?   1.000000
 2 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0           725670          ?   2.000000
 3 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       1.4378e+06          ?   3.000000
 4 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0        2.178e+06          ?   4.000000
 5 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       2.8806e+06          ?   5.000000
 6 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       3.5353e+06          ?   6.000000
 7 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       4.1598e+06          ?   7.000000
 8 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       4.7729e+06          ?   8.000000
 9 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       5.3924e+06          ?   9.000000
10 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       6.0281e+06          ?  10.000000
```

I need to extract just two values from each row:

```
191340
725670
1.4378e+06
2.178e+06
.... etc

1.00000
2.00000
3.00000
4.00000
.... etc
```

This code:

```
import csv
with open('NGC1365GaiaPhotomLogTestTenLines.dat', "rb") as infile:
read = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in read :
        print (row)
```

Generates:

```
['         1 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0           191340          ?   1.000000']
['         2 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0           725670          ?   2.000000']
['         3 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       1.4378e+06          ?   3.000000']
['         4 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0        2.178e+06          ?   4.000000']
['         5 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       2.8806e+06          ?   5.000000']
['         6 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       3.5353e+06          ?   6.000000']
['         7 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       4.1598e+06          ?   7.000000']
['         8 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       4.7729e+06          ?   8.000000']
['         9 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       5.3924e+06          ?   9.000000']
['        10 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       6.0281e+06          ?  10.000000']
```

Problem is that the lists produced are not nice items separated by commas - the items in the input file are separated by spaces, and the number of spaces can vary because the format of the values in the first column can also vary.

I though wasn't going to be dificult but I've consulted loads of threads and got nowhere.

Comment: simply `line.split()`. Note `csv.reader` is an overkill in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the other answers here, I think you *should* use the `csv` module.  If your files contain headers or quoted fields, you'll be much happier than if you tried modifying your custom solution after the fact:

```
with open('filename') as infile:
    r = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in r:
        print(row)
```

Your file looks like it might be tab-separated on your computer.  In that case you would change `delimiter=' '` to `delimiter='\t'` in the above.

You could also use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), which has a more general whitespace mode

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename", header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: Nope, definitely spaces, note how the values are right-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to @Eugen Constantin Dinca &  @tobias_k for simplifying code

```
with open('csv.dat', "rb") as infile:
  for row in infile:
    print row.split()
```

Output:

```
['1', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '191340', '?', '1.000000']
['2', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '725670', '?', '2.000000']
['3', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '1.4378e+06', '?', '3.000000']
['4', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '2.178e+06', '?', '4.000000']
['5', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '2.8806e+06', '?', '5.000000']
['6', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '3.5353e+06', '?', '6.000000']
['7', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '4.1598e+06', '?', '7.000000']
['8', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '4.7729e+06', '?', '8.000000']
['9', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '5.3924e+06', '?', '9.000000']
['10', '1011.720000', '1830.340000', '0', '0', '0', '6.0281e+06', '?', '10.000000']
```

Comment: Noting that, at least in Python 2, calling `row.split()` is enough as when `sep is not specified or is None` then  `runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.` (from https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca thanks, you are right. I'm not a python guy

Comment: There's really no point in using `csv.reader` here. Just read the lines directly `for row in infile:` and split `print(row.split())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you can use

Also a couple of points about your code `csv.reader` is an overkill. Everything is done using simply built-ins - that is no external dependencies.

Also using variable names like `read` is not a very good idea.

```
lines = """1 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0           191340          ?   1.000000
 2 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0           725670          ?   2.000000
 3 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       1.4378e+06          ?   3.000000
 4 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0        2.178e+06          ?   4.000000
 5 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       2.8806e+06          ?   5.000000
 6 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       3.5353e+06          ?   6.000000
 7 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       4.1598e+06          ?   7.000000
 8 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       4.7729e+06          ?   8.000000
 9 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       5.3924e+06          ?   9.000000
10 1011.720000 1830.340000            0            0            0       6.0281e+06          ?  10.000000"""

for line in lines.split("\n"):
    toks = line.split() # This should split the line into tokens separated by one or more white space characters. 

    if len(toks) == 9: # Just to make sure there are enough tokens. 
        # do whatever you want
        print (toks[6])
```

Comment: well - yes but it's not a 'built-in' agreed it's from standard lib.